# Making .ui-btn-left larger

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

Quick question which I haven't found an exact answer to online. I'm very new to Javascript so this is probably quite a simple issue. I am trying to make the close button on a jQuery page larger.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-header .ui-btn-left {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
}
```

I know if I specify a height and width this will make the button larger, but how do I preferably increase the size of the icon to match or at least make it centre on the button?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean with "...increase the size of the icon to match or at least make it centre on the button?".. how are we supposed to know without any HTML?

Comment: Agreed; your HTML could make a big difference in the way your desired result can be solved.  Also, are you using jQuery UI? or custom CSS only?  Do you have an additional custom CSS file?

Comment: Can you give a fiddle or something? It would depend on what the icon is?  Is it an image? font?

Comment: I am using JQuery mobile 1.3.2 and the .ui-btn-left seems to be using a default icon/style. This is part of a huge project that I have just joined so I am trying to create a JSFiddle to display my problem but dividing out the relevant code isn't a trivial task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem in the end. I had to remove the default close button and just create my own. This might help someone else who is trying to do the same thing. The data-close-btn turns off the default close button.

The data-icon just tell it to use the custom icon, it was more straight forward than I was making it.

```
#btnCancel .ui-btn-inner {
    width: 33px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
}

.ui-icon-custom 
{
   background-image: url(../images/image.png) !important;
   background-position: 0px -84px;
   width: 33px;
   height: 35px;
   margin: 0 !important;
   box-shadow:none;
} 

<html>
   <head>
    <title>Change Language</title>   
   </head>

   <body>

     <div data-role="page" id="changeLanguage" data-close-btn="none">
       <header data-role="header">
           <h1 data-translation-key="choose language" ></h1>
           <a id="btnCancel" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="custom" data-rel="back" data-    iconpos="notext" ></a>
       </header>

       <div data-role="content">
         <p data-translation-key="pick language"></p>       
         <ul id="languageSelection"></ul>
       </div>

       <p class="version"></p>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```